# go filepath.Walk walking behavior

Tags: go

In my code filepath.Walk walks over directories, in the examples all directories are called dir

```
1.  dir
2.  dir
10.  dir
100.  dir
etc
```

when walking over the directories it will see

```
1.  dir
10.  dir
2.  dir
```

how do i make my own walkFunc so it goes trough directories like this,

```
1.  dir
2.  dir 
10.  dir
```

Comment: Are those supposed to be directory names, that you want sorted numerically? From the `Walk` documentation: `The files are walked in lexical order," -- you need to implement your own walk to sort them differently, or sort them after walk in complete.

Comment: i am renaming 300.000 directories to have numbers in front of them and i change around 200 at a time because people are working in the file system while it is being updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Walk) `filepath.Walk` traverses entries in lexical order.

If you want to list them in a different order, you can either:

- do your own traversal using [File.ReadDirNames](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Readdirnames)
- call `filepath.Walk`, put all the paths into a slice, and sort it as desired.